# How to capture the traffic of a computer in my LAN?

Tags: windows, linux, man-in-the-middle, sniffer

I have a machine with the Windows 10 preview installed and I want to capture all the traffic it sends for a day and then block all the MS hosts it sent data to without my direct permission.
I don't want to do this with Wireshark on that computer because Microsoft might have implemented [their keylogger](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/preview-privacy-statement) hidden on lower levels.
But I know that you can capture traffic from other computers on your LAN using a so called MITM attack. So I'm looking for a tool which can do that and some instructions.
Preferably a tool for Windows, but if it is easier on Linux or there simply is no tool for that for Windows then I would be okay with Linux (in a VM)..

Comment: This part cracked me up " because Microsoft might have implemented their keylogger hidden on lower levels. ". I would love to hear why you believe that.

Comment: @alexander7567 Well, they are definitely logging every of your keystrokes and are sending them to their servers, this is not secret. And I just want to be on the safe side, that's why I don't want to rely on a program on this system for checking the traffic.

Comment: Show me factual evidence that they are logging your every keystroke..

Comment: @alexander7567 Sure check this: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/preview-privacy-statement  [...]we may collect typed characters and use them for purposes such as improving autocomplete and spellcheck features [...] voice input features like speech-to-text, we may collect voice information and use it for purposes such as improving speech processing[...]

Comment: Why all these down votes? It would be nice if you could at least tell me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Previews have different privacy policies than general-release operating systems. In my case, I've downvoted due to a misunderstanding of how Wireshark works. Wireshark captures low level information easily enough; unless you are imputing that Microsoft is deliberately subverting Wireshark. If they don't tamper with bit-torrent apps or virus workshop tools, they won't tamper with the security sector's favourite network analysis tool.

Comment: Of course previews have different privacy policies than general-release operating systems. Did I ever say something else? And I'm sorry that I'm concerned about my privacy, but Microsoft logging all of your keystrokes doesn't sound like the best PR to me, so I can definitely see why MS would implement the keylogger on a lower level. They might also just do it for security reasons, so that other programs can't read the keys by sniffing on the traffic. And I know how Wiresharks works, there is no misunderstanding.

Comment: How low can a keylogger be for it to be deeper than traffic? If something can be caught with a proxy (mitm), then it can be caught on the host's network card.

Comment: I'm sure there are lots of ways Microsoft could accomplish this. Depending on how much Wireshark relies on Win API functions this could be pretty easy. But I bet MS could deny direct access to the network device and provide a similar looking interface which just filters the system traffic. What I am most concerned about though, is the time during booting/startup and shutdown. I really don't think that Wireshark is the way to go, at least not on the same computer.

Comment: It's public knowledge that some keystrokes are being sent to microsoft, so I think it's highly unlikely that they would intentionally subvert wireshark to hide this information especially considering that the captures can be done from another device, as you're trying to do.  Plus, your computer's communication with microsoft is likely encrypted so you probably won't be able  to see what it's sending anyway.  TBH if privacy is your primary concern, don't use the preview.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do to view traffic is connect it to a router that supports packet forwarding and run wire shark or security onion on a sperate computer. I know using firewall rules on the router (installing dd-wrt will allow it) will accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to capture traffic by using a second machine, then run a packet sniffer (Wireshark, for example) on that second machine while it is connected via a hub (or spanned/mirrored port) with the Win10 machine. It will capture all packets it sees being sent by the Win10 machine. You could do a packet forwarding scenario on the second machine, but that can be complicated.

Alternatively to blacklisting the Microsoft destinations, you could whitelist the destinations you want the Win10 machine to connect to. That way, you can ensure that only the destinations you specify receive communication, and if there is a large number of Microsoft destinations that Win10 might send to, you're still covered if they make a change.

Answer (score 0):

Paranoia aside, I would suggest looking into cheap network taps. You can plug the system's interface into it and then plug the monitoring port into another system's spare interface. This other system should be running tcpdump or wireshark on the spare interface.

Comment: But it can be solved on a software level, so I don't see why I should buy additional hardware for this.

Comment: If you don't trust your operating system, then no, it can't.

Comment: I am not talking about the software on that computer. I am talking about MITM attacks which can be done from another computer on the same network.

Comment: If you have a computer with 2 network interfaces, you can use it as your gateway and sniff all the traffic on this second computer. But it's basically easier to just buy a hub and plug any computer on this hub.